# Handling LaTeX errors

Tags: errors

I have bash script that generates several tex files when it is run and then uses `latex` and `dvipdfm` to generate a pdf file. The only problem I have is that when something fails `latex` will halt the process and ask for input on the errors. In this case I am generating more than one pdf and `latex` is called several times for each one. So I end up with the same errors several times and I have to mash through it.

Since this is being integrated into the build process for something else I would like to find a way to just let the script die with just a single message.

To recap I would like to have latex terminate when there is an error so that when people other than my self run this they are stuck trying to kill this script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call `latex` with the `-halt-on-error` option and the `-interaction=nonstopmode` option:

```
 latex -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex
```

Comment: I am absolutely dumb founded that I didn't see this when looking at the latex command, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I would do `-interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error` or `-interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error`. Using `-halt-on-error` by itself will still pause for user input in certain situations, such as a missing package.

Comment: @frabjous Good point, updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: An alternative (on UNIX-like machines) is to force LaTeX to read from /dev/null: `latex file_name < /dev/null`. When LaTeX asks /dev/null to answer some inane question, /dev/null nicely responds with EOF, and LaTeX in turn dies with "Emergency stop!" (and gives a non-zero status to boot, which is very nice for makefiles).